# source code of server that creates multiple servlet threads to handle concurrent requests

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, concurrency, server

Folks,

I have been trying to understand how the server creates multiple servlet threads to handle each concurrent request appropriately and delegates these request details to service() method of the Servlet instance.

**I want to understand and analyze the server's source-code or a specific set of classes to understand this creation & maintenance of concurrent request processing through multi-threading.**

**My understanding/assumption** : There will be unanimous servlet instance per mapping and all the concurrent requests would be served by individual servlet thread (**spawn by the server - which is exactly the multi-threading process I want to know in detail/source-code**) that would be executed separately within its own stack.

Comment: Check this link you will get better idea [How do servlets work ?] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-sessions-shared-variables-and-multithreadi)

Comment: There are plenty of open source servlet engines with the source available for your examination.